# Does syncing ~/.asdf/installs between multiple computers cause problems?

Tags: asdf-vm

I noticed that `~/.asdf/installs` is by far the largest subfolder there, and thus wondered whether is it safe to sync?

In a local network where several computers use asdf for a somewhat overlapping set of its plugins, it would be beneficial to download a new plugin (version) once and have each next `asdf install` command reuse the existing data.

---

In my experience, doing the same with `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads` is possible:

```
brew install …
==> Downloading https://…
Already downloaded: …
```

And I see in [the docs](http://asdf-vm.com/manage/configuration.html#always-keep-download) that one can configure `~/.asdf/downloads` to retain the raw downloads, so syncing that should be fine. But what about the `installs` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

**`~/.asdf/downloads`** - It depends on whether your syncing between different operating systems, and whether the plugins you are using download different archives of the tool based on the current OS. What exactly is stored in the downloads sub directory for each plugin is up to creators of the plugins. Some plugins may need to download OS-specific archives.

- **If you are syncing between computers with the same OS syncing will this will work.**
- **If the plugins you are using downloads the same archive regardless of OS, this will work**

**`~/.asdf/installs`** - Typically plugins compile code for the current OS, and may also link to any libraries you have installed. If you have two computers with the exact same OS and libraries installed this should work. Otherwise you **might** be able to get this to work, but there are no guarantees and I'd advise against it.